# Filter with a button in wenzhixin bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have in my site a wenzhixin bootstrap table which is working perfect, but I want to add a button in the toolbar which performs an automatic filter.

I tried both to apply a 'filterBy' and 'refresh' querying the proper data in my data json file but all the data remains in the table.

These are the examples:

```
$("#btn").click( function () { 
     $('#table').bootstrapTable('refresh', {query: {field:"value"}});
} );
```

and:

```
$("#btn").click( function () { 
     $('#table').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {field:"value"});
} );
```

I made a minimal codeply and works perfect! [codeply.com/go/HeTKpgL0ej](http://codeply.com/go/HeTKpgL0ej) But in my real example didn't work!! [sbg.qb.fcen.uba.ar:2019/results_crystal/P00439/1J8U](http://sbg.qb.fcen.uba.ar:2019/results_crystal/P00439/1J8U) What is happening??

Comment: Using filterBy works fine for me. Maybe show your table code and actual field you are trying to filter on?

Comment: I made a minimal codeply and works perfect! http://www.codeply.com/go/HeTKpgL0ej

But in my real example didn't work!! http://sbg.qb.fcen.uba.ar:2019/results_crystal/P00439/1J8U 

What is happening??

Comment: I think I see the problem, and it's probably an oversight, but I think you are using the wrong field. I think you meant to use pdb_pos instead of pdb_res

Comment: No, It was a mistake of me, but if you execute 

$('#sequence-table').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {pdb_pos:"140"});

in the console, it didnt work. I fix that in my site an also didnt work.

Comment: It seems the search isn't working either